Nesting leave cell blank in INT formula Excel
I have date/time differences I want to show between pt admission and discharges in excel.
My formula works if have dates for both.  However, if no pt discharge, my formula shows #num! error.
If I try add a nested (a2="","") or similar argument at the front or end of the formula, I get the same error.  Just want the cell to show blank
Formula I'm using is:
=IF(INT(AD3-AC3)>0,INT(AD3-AC3)&" d, ","")&IF(HOUR(AD3-AC3)>0,HOUR(AD3-AC3)&" hr and ","")&IF(MINUTE(AD3-AC3)>0,MINUTE(AD3-AC3)&" mins","")
I've tried a few different things, but I can't seem to get any further.
For another calculation of time this works:
=IF(N2="","",DATEDIF(K2,N2,"d"))
Ive tried nesting isblank in front, or marking the cell "","", or adding a line on end of formula where if =<0,"","" too
I'm sure it's something simple, but struggling with nesting formulas
Any and all assistance is greatly appreciated :-)

=IF(AD3="","",IF(INT(AD3-AC3)>0,INT(AD3-AC3)&" d, ","")&IF(HOUR(AD3-AC3)>0,HOUR(AD3-AC3)&" hr and ","")&IF(MINUTE(AD3-AC3)>0,MINUTE(AD3-AC3)&" mins",""))

Maybe this is useful: =LET(x,LAMBDA(y,LET(z,HSTACK(INT(y),HOUR(y),MINUTE(y)),TEXTJOIN(" & ",,IF(z,TEXT(z,{"0 \d","0 \h","0 \m"}),"")))),x(AD3-AC3))

@SpectralInstance - thankyou so much! That works. A simple change that I couldn't see wood for the trees. Cheers

@P.b. thanks, I tried it a few times but no dice.  Im new to excel formulas and this is way over my head. Thanks though!

No worries. The more you try, the further you get. I got there that way too.
